# What's the difference between std::merge and std::set_union?

Tags: c++, merge

The question is clear, my google- and cplusplus.com/reference-fu is failing me.

Comment: @Emilie: As I said in my question, that did *not* provide me with an answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`std::set_union`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) will contain those elements that are present in both sets only once. [`std::merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) will contain them twice.

For example, with `A = {1, 2, 5}; B = {2, 3, 4}`:

- union will give `C = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`
- merge will give `D = {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Both work on sorted ranges, and return a sorted result.

Short example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::set<int> A = {1, 2, 5};
  std::set<int> B = {2, 3, 4};

  std::vector<int> out;
  std::set_union(std::begin(A), std::end(A), std::begin(B), std::end(B),
                 std::back_inserter(out));
  for (auto i : out)
  {
    std::cout << i << " ";
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  out.clear();
  std::merge(std::begin(A), std::end(A), std::begin(B), std::end(B),
             std::back_inserter(out));
  for (auto i : out)
  {
    std::cout << i << " ";
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: `std::merge` also works on sorted ranges and produces a sorted result.

Comment: @Charkes Bailey: thanks, I hadn't checked std::merge and didn't think it did that. Amended my answer.

Comment: Just for everyone's sake, maybe it's me being picky, but the above isn't clear enough for my liking. Reading this answer *might* lead you to believe  that duplicates are eliminated by set_union() - they are, though not necessarily in the way you might think. If the first range contains an equivalent element more than once, that element will appear in the output range just as many times. This is easily verified:

Comment: (sorry, still new to stackoverflow, that verification couldn't be displayed as code in the comment, so I've created a new answer with details)

Comment: I agree it is a very unclear answer. It implies that set_union actually works as an intersection, not a union.

Answer (score 6):

`std::merge` keeps all elements from both ranges, equivalent elements from the first range preceding equivalent elements from the second range in the output. Where an equivalent elements appear in both ranges `std::set_union` takes only the element from the first range, otherwise each element is merged in order as with `std::merge`.

References: ISO/IEC 14882:2003 25.3.4 [lib.alg.merge] and 25.3.5.2 [lib.set.union].

Comment: this sounds more like intersection, doesn't it?

Comment: @davka: I'm talking about the behaviour where an equivalent exists in the second range. I took it as read that all elements without an equivalent in the other range are retained. I have clarified my wording.

Comment: ok, after reading the sentence 5 times :) I see what you mean. I read it as "only takes"...

Comment: @davka: Please read more carefully, I said "takes only" which I think is clearer.

Comment: I'll do my best :) your new phrasing is much clearer, me think. for many of us English is the 2nd (or nth) language

Answer (score 2):

This is the verification I suggested in the comment I posted to the accepted answer (i.e. that if an element is present in one of the input-sets N times, it will appear N times in the output of set_union - so set_union does *not* remove duplicate equivalent items in the way we would 'naturally' or 'mathematically' expect - if, however, both input-ranges contained a common item once only, then set_union would *appear* to remove the duplicate)

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

void printer(int i) { cout << i << ", "; }

int main() {
    int mynumbers1[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4 }; // this is sorted, 3 is dupe
    int mynumbers2[] = { 5 };                // this is sorted


    vector<int> union_result(10);
    set_union(mynumbers1, mynumbers1 + sizeof(mynumbers1)/sizeof(int),
              mynumbers2, mynumbers2 + sizeof(mynumbers2)/sizeof(int),
              union_result.begin());
    for_each(union_result.begin(), union_result.end(), printer);

    return 0;
}
```

This will print: 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0,

Answer (score 1):

`std::merge` merges all elements, without eliminating the duplicates, while `std::set_union` eliminates the duplicates. That is, the latter applies the rule of [**union**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29) operation of [**set theory**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory).

Comment: Why was I only thinking of these algorithms in terms of a `std::set`... Thanks for the in my eyes shorted and cleanest answer.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous answers - beware that the complexity of `std::set_union` is twice that of `std::merge`. In practise, this means the comparator in `std::set_union` may be applied to an element *after* it has been dereferenced, while with `std::merge` this is never the case.

Why may this be important? Consider something like:

```
std::vector<Foo> lhs, rhs;
```

And you want to produce a union of `lhs` and `rhs`:

```
std::set_union(std::cbegin(lhs), std::cend(lhs),
               std::cbegin(rhs), std::cend(rhs),
               std::back_inserter(union));
```

But now suppose `Foo` is not copyable, or is very expensive to copy and you don't need the originals. You may think to use:

```
std::set_union(std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(lhs)),
               std::make_move_iterator(std::end(lhs)),
               std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(rhs)),
               std::make_move_iterator(std::end(rhs)),
               std::back_inserter(union));
```

But this is undefined behaviour as there is a possibility of a moved `Foo` being compared! The correct solution is therefore:

```
std::merge(std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(lhs)),
           std::make_move_iterator(std::end(lhs)),
           std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(rhs)),
           std::make_move_iterator(std::end(rhs)),
           std::back_inserter(union));
union.erase(std::unique(std::begin(union), std::end(union), std::end(union));
```

Which has the same complexity as `std::set_union`.